# Kubernetes deployments and services

Tags: kubernetes, networking

If I have two deployments running within the same namespace, and one service exposing deployment A, how can I make Deploymet B use the same service to only expose the 20 % of the PODS running on that deployment? How can I make the Service to Load Balance the deployment in such way that the Deploy A that have 5 replicas running already all exposed through that service, and make deployment B to use the service only for the 20% of the PODS running on it

Comment: This isn't easy to accomplish OTB. In most cases you need a service mesh, although the nginx ingress does somewhat offer this functionality. Have a look at https://flagger.app/. Are you trying to do A/B testing or canary releases?

Comment: `...make Deploymet B use the same service to only expose the 20 % of the PODS running on that deployment...` - what is this `same service` and what do you mean `make deployment B to use the service only for the 20%`? Where is the other 80%?

Comment: Could you please clarify - you want to make requests from deployment B to the only 20 % of the pods in deployment A? So, in your example, deployment B will send request to the 1 pod from A deployment (5 replicas)?

Comment: This is for canary deployments, the Service is a nodeport type service, and there is a Deployment running already qith 5 replicas, the Deployment B, will be the canary one, and only 20 % of the 5 replicas running on it will be usign the Nodeport service already running on the cluster

Comment: This is to make the service be a LB for both deployments, most likely

Answer (score 1):

For canary deployments, you will have two deployments and one service (as you have already).

Let say, Your first deployment is 'stable' and the other one is 'canary'. **Both have the same match labels** matching with service, so that service can load-balance to both deployments.
Based on your example the 'stable' deployment has 5 replicas, in that case, you should deploy your 'canary' deployment with 1 replica (20 % of total replicas needed) and deploy it. I think that's what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: hmm interesting Thanks you

Comment: makes sense thanks